# Display the Results of an If Statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have an if statement in my code that I can't seem to get to display.  I keep getting undefined(output3).  This is a calculation to determine the days until next birthdate.  Basically if the birth date has already passed, it adds one year to the birthdate and subtracts the current date.  How would I display this in the statement at top of JS code along with the other statements that display when the Calculate button is pressed?  Thx!

This is the main block of code that's giving me fits on how to display it.

```
if (diff.cbdiff < 0 ) {

            var date = new Date(currentBday); 
            date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);
            document.getElementById('output3').innerHTML= ((date-date2)/(1000*60*60*24));
            console.log(output3);
        } else {
            document.getElementById('output3').innerHTML=diff.cbdiff;
             console.log(output3);
        }
```

Here is complete JS code:

```js
function calc() {
  var date1 = new Date();
  var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById("date2").value);
  var diff = dateDiff(date1, date2);
  var output = "You are " + diff.year + " year" + "s " + diff.month + " month" + "s And " + diff.day + " day" + "s Old";
  var output1 = "You are " + diff.days + " day" + "S" + "old";
  var output2 = "You are " + diff.secondsalive + " seconds" + "old";
  var output3 = "It is " + output3 + " days until your next Birthday";

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = output1;
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = output2;
  document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = output3;

  console.log(date1);
  console.log(date2);
}

function dateDiff(date1, date2) {
  if (date1 > date2) return dateDiff(date2, date1);
  var diff = {};
  //console.log(currentBday);

  diff.secondsalive = ((date2 - date1) / (1000)).toLocaleString({
    undefined,
    maximumFractionDigits: 1
  });
  diff.day = date2.getDate() - date1.getDate();
  diff.days = ((date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toFixed(1);
  diff.year = date2.getFullYear() - date1.getFullYear();
  diff.month = date2.getMonth() - date1.getMonth();

  var currentBdYear = date2.getFullYear();
  var currentBdMonth = date1.getMonth() + 1;
  var currentBdDay = date1.getDate();
  var currentYearBD = (diff.year + date2);

  var addDate = new Date(diff.year);
  //console.log(addDate);

  var currentBday = new Date(currentBdMonth + "/" + currentBdDay + "/" + currentBdYear);
  diff.cbdiff = ((currentBday - date2) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toFixed(0);
  console.log(diff.cbdiff);

  if (diff.cbdiff < 0) {
    var date = new Date(currentBday);
    date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);
    document.getElementById('output3').innerHTML = ((date - date2) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    console.log(output3);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('output3').innerHTML = diff.cbdiff;
    console.log(output3);
  }

  if (diff.day < 0) {
    diff.month--;
    var dayDiff = new Date(date2.getYear(), date2.getMonth(), 0).getDate() - date1.getDate();
    diff.day = date2.getDate();
    if (dayDiff > 0) {
      diff.day += dayDiff;
    }
  }
  if (diff.month < 0) {
    diff.month += 12;
    diff.year--;
  }

  return diff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body id="gradient">
  <div>
    <h1>Birthday Calculator</h1>
    <h2> Enter Birthday</h2>
    <td>BirthDate:</td>
    <input id="date2" value="10/1/74" />
    <button onclick="calc()" style="height:50px">Calculate</button>
    <br><br>
    <table class="center">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="output"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="output1"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="output2"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="output3"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <p It is id="output3"></p>

    <h3></h3>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have `var output3 = "It is " +output3+ " days until your next Birthday";`. What are you expecting `output3` to be if you're just declaring it on that line? Where did you calculate the number of days?

Comment: Is that supposed to be `diff.cbdiff`?

Comment: Yes if that condition in the if statement is >0 it is diff.cbdiff.  Otherwise it should be ((date - date2) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var output3 = "It is " + output3 + " days until your next Birthday";
```

`output3` is the variable you're declaring, it doesn't contain the number of days until your next birthday. That's in `diff.cbdiff`.

Another problem is that `dateDiff()` is writing the corrected difference to the `output3` DIV. But `calc()` overwrites that using `diff.cbdiff`. So `dateDiff()` should just put the corrected difference in `diff.cbdiff` rather than the DOM.

```js
function calc() {
  var date1 = new Date();
  var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById("date2").value);
  var diff = dateDiff(date1, date2);
  var output = "You are " + diff.year + " year" + "s " + diff.month + " month" + "s And " + diff.day + " day" + "s Old";
  var output1 = "You are " + diff.days + " day" + "S" + "old";
  var output2 = "You are " + diff.secondsalive + " seconds" + "old";
  var output3 = "It is " + diff.cbdiff + " days until your next Birthday";

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = output1;
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = output2;
  document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = output3;

  console.log(date1);
  console.log(date2);
}

function dateDiff(date1, date2) {
  if (date1 > date2) return dateDiff(date2, date1);
  var diff = {};
  //console.log(currentBday);

  diff.secondsalive = ((date2 - date1) / (1000)).toLocaleString({
    undefined,
    maximumFractionDigits: 1
  });
  diff.day = date2.getDate() - date1.getDate();
  diff.days = ((date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toFixed(1);
  diff.year = date2.getFullYear() - date1.getFullYear();
  diff.month = date2.getMonth() - date1.getMonth();

  var currentBdYear = date2.getFullYear();
  var currentBdMonth = date1.getMonth() + 1;
  var currentBdDay = date1.getDate();
  var currentYearBD = (diff.year + date2);

  var addDate = new Date(diff.year);
  //console.log(addDate);

  var currentBday = new Date(currentBdMonth + "/" + currentBdDay + "/" + currentBdYear);
  diff.cbdiff = ((currentBday - date2) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toFixed(0);
  console.log(currentBday, diff.cbdiff);

  if (diff.cbdiff < 0) {
    var date = new Date(currentBday);
    date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);
    diff.cbdiff = ((date - date2) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toFixed(0);
    console.log(diff.cbdiff);
  }

  if (diff.day < 0) {
    diff.month--;
    var dayDiff = new Date(date2.getYear(), date2.getMonth(), 0).getDate() - date1.getDate();
    diff.day = date2.getDate();
    if (dayDiff > 0) {
      diff.day += dayDiff;
    }
  }
  if (diff.month < 0) {
    diff.month += 12;
    diff.year--;
  }

  return diff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body id="gradient">
  <div>
    <h1>Birthday Calculator</h1>
    <h2> Enter Birthday</h2>
    <td>BirthDate:</td>
    <input id="date2" value="10/1/74" />
    <button onclick="calc()" style="height:50px">Calculate</button>
    <br><br>
    <table class="center">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="output"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="output1"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="output2"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="output3"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <p It is id="output3"></p>

    <h3></h3>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that nullify the whole reason for the if statement.  Because it either needs to be diff.cbdiff OR ((date - date2) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); I thought there would be a way to display the result of whichever returned true?  Am I not thinking about that correctly?

Comment: The `if` statement should update `diff.cbdiff`, not update the DOM.

Comment: And i tried the code, but if the birthdate is before today, then it computes as a negative number.  E.g. 6/1/19 shows negative 73 days until next birthday.  So i needed it to calculate the days until next 6/1/20, which is what i was trying to accomplish with the if statement.

Comment: Have you tried my current code? I had a typo earlier where I wrote `date.cbdiff` instead of `diff.cbdiff`. It took me 15 minutes to figure that out!

Comment: Oh.  That's really awesome!   How does that work when there is no else statement?

Comment: You don't need an `else` statement because it already contains the correct value. It's being displayed in `calc()`, you don't need to display it in `dateDiff()`.

Answer (score 1):

output3 is undefined because it is not a variable. It is the id of an html element. You didn't declare what output3 is